# R - sum each element in a vector with each element of other vector

Tags: r, vector

I have two vectors and I want a new vector which elements are the sum of an element of vector 1 and an element of vector 2.

```
v1<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
v2<-c(0,1,1,2,2,1)

for(i in 1:length(v1)){
  for(j in 1:length(v2)){
    n<-vector()
    n<-v1[i]+v2[j]
  }
  m<-NULL
  m[n]<-m
}
```

When I run the loop, I get `m=NULL` and `n` is numeric class with `NA`. Any idea?

Comment: why nested loops if it can be achieved by simple `v1 + v2`

Comment: `d` is not defined and you're assigning `NULL` to `m` every time you do a loop. That's probably why you're getting that result.

Comment: You are overwriting `n` again and again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps we need

```
tapply(c(v1, v2), c(v1, v2), FUN = sum)
```

Or just

```
v1 + v2
```

Or could be `outer`

```
outer(v1, v2, FUN = "+")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to correct your code, you can try something like this:

```
v1<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
v2<-c(0,1,1,2,2,1)

m<-matrix(rep(0,length(v1)*length(v2)), nrow=length(v1))
for(i in 1:length(v1)){
  for(j in 1:length(v2)){
    m[i,j] <- v1[i]+v2[j]
  }
}
m
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    2    2    3    3    2
[2,]    2    3    3    4    4    3
[3,]    3    4    4    5    5    4
[4,]    4    5    5    6    6    5
[5,]    5    6    6    7    7    6
[6,]    6    7    7    8    8    7
```

This can also be done this way

```
outer(v1, v2, FUN='+')
```

or in this way

```
matrix(apply(expand.grid(1:length(v1), 1:length(v2))[2:1], 1, 
                         function(x)v1[x[1]]+v2[x[2]]), nrow=length(v1), byrow=TRUE)
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    2    2    3    3    2
[2,]    2    3    3    4    4    3
[3,]    3    4    4    5    5    4
[4,]    4    5    5    6    6    5
[5,]    5    6    6    7    7    6
[6,]    6    7    7    8    8    7
```